# Is it possible to copy a file in a UITests target to the documents directory of the app?

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, xcuitest

I have a sample text file in my UITests target. I want to copy this file to the documents directory of the app so that when I perform tests on uploading of file in my app, I can select it via Files app and upload it.

Comment: Have you updated your info plist to include `LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace` and `UIFileSharingEnabled` or `UISupportsDocumentBrowser`?  ([check out this article for example](https://www.appcoda.com/files-app-integration/))

Also if you want upvotes you should update your question with more detail, indicating what you have tried and provide information to reproduce the problem: [more info here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: i will check that out. thank you.

Comment: i added those keys in the plist but still the file is not found in the files app during UI testing. however, i managed to use application's launch arguments to pass the url of the file to be copied and also the custom name when copied to the destination. by using this, the file is now visible in the files app.

Answer (score 6):

This is possible by using the XCUIApplication's launchArguments. It needs to include the following keys in the plist of the App: `LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace` and `UIFileSharingEnabled` or `UISupportsDocumentBrowser`.

```
// File: FileUploadUITests.swift
// Target: UITests
func launchApplication() {
    let fileName = "__File_12345678910.txt"
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    app.launchArguments.append("-fileUrlPath")
    app.launchArguments.append(sampleTextFileURL().path)
    app.launchArguments.append("-fileName")
    app.launchArguments.append(fileName)
    app.launch()
}

func sampleTextFileURL() -> URL {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: FileUploadUITests.self)
    return bundle.url(forResource: "text_file_example", withExtension: "txt")!
}

// File: TestHelper.swift
// Target: App
@discardableResult
func processArgumentsForTesting() -> Bool {
    if let index = ProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments.index(where: { $0 == "-fileUrlPath" }) {
        let path = ProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments[index + 1]
        let url = URL(string: path)!
        let fileName: String?
        if let index = ProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments.index(where: { $0 == "-fileName" }) {
            fileName = ProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments[index + 1]
        } else {
            fileName = nil
        }
        copyTestFileToDocumentDirectory(url: url, fileName: fileName)
        return true
    }
    return false
}

private let fileManager = FileManager.default

private var documentDirectoryURLOfTheApp: URL {
    let paths = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .allDomainsMask)
    let documentDirectoryPath = paths.first!
    return documentDirectoryPath
}


@discardableResult
private func copyTestFileToDocumentDirectory(url: URL, fileName: String? = nil) -> Bool {
    let directory = documentDirectoryURLOfTheApp
    let destination = directory.appendingPathComponent(fileName ?? url.lastPathComponent).path
    let isOkay: Bool
    do {
        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: destination) {
            try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: destination)
        }
        try fileManager.copyItem(atPath: url.path, toPath: destination)
        isOkay = true
    } catch {
        isOkay = false
    }
    return isOkay
}

// File: AppDelegate.swift
// Target: App
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    processArgumentsForTesting()
    return true
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to place a file in the doc folder in macOS for a sandboxed app?