# iOS Testing local file import/opening in Xcode UITest

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing

in my UITests, I'd like to download a file from a feature in my app and save it to the local iPhone storage and then open it. I managed to download and save but it couldn't find a way to record the file opening (using the iOS basic files).

Do you know a way to code a test that control the file import or I need to create a bypass in the app code.

When I try to record the test I've got the "Timestamped Event Matching Error: Failed to find matching element" error (and I couldn't solve it)

Thanks

Comment: Here is a solution where launch-arguments are used to place a file in user docs from the apps bundle: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58616797/5389500

Answer (score 0):

You can only record interactions with AUT using built in recorder.

You have to write code by yourself if you want to interact with other apps. Use ‘XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier:)’ or [www.GitHub.com/rzakhar/xctapps](http://www.GitHub.com/rzakhar/xctapps) to enable interacting with the other apps